# IIS7 Virtual Directory Redirects

Tags: iis, iis-7

On our old IIS6 server, we handled IIS redirects by:

- Setting up a virtual directory on the site
- Pointing the virtual directory to a physical path on the server
- In the VD properties, set it to redirect to a URL

I'm trying to replicate this in IIS7 by doing the following:

- Set up a virtual directory on the site
- Point the virtual directory to a physical path on the server
- In the VD features, double click on HTTP Redirect and add the URL to redirect to.

This works fine if I only have one virtual directory. If I add another, the settings in the second VD overwrite the settings of the first!

Is this a common issue, and has anyone found a workaround? Anything would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you configure an HTTP Redirect in IIS 7 for a Virtual Directory it creates a web.config file in the physical path.  The work around is to point each Virtual Directory to a unique physical path.

I use folder structure like this:
\path\redirects[site_name][virtual_dir_name]