# Configuring a reverse proxy on IIS 6 with Isape_Rewrite3

Tags: iis-6, reverse-proxy, isapi-rewrite

I'm running IIS6 on Windows Server 2003.

I am trying to set up a tool on one of my websites that requires a reverse proxy.

As I understand it, I need to capture a script reference pointing at `my.domain.com/toolname/subfolder/javascript.js` to pull the file from `library.provider.com/javascript.js`.

---

The examples given by the tool provider are,

"In Apache2, add this to your `<VirtualHost>` entry for the site:"

```
ProxyPass /subfolder/ http://library.provider.com/
ProxyPassReverse /subfolder/ http://library.provider.com/
```

"In NGINX, add this to your `server` block for the site:"

```
location /subfolder/ {
    proxy_pass http://library.provider.com/;
}
```

---

I tried the example found in the SO question, [URL Rewrite of a subdirectory to a different domain using IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392522/url-rewrite-of-a-subdirectory-to-a-different-domain-using-iis), adjusting it to my situation:

```
RewriteCond Host: (.*)
RewriteRule ^/subfolder/$|^/subfolder/(.*) http://library.provider.com/$1 [P]
```

This did not appear to work... the RewriteLog looks like this:

```
... (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /subfolder/javascript.js
... (1) Htaccess process request [drive]:[path]\httpd.conf
... (1) Htaccess process request [drive]:[path]\my.domain.com\.htaccess
... (3) applying pattern '^/subfolder/$|^/subfolder/(.*)' to uri 'subfolder/javascript.js'
```

I notice that the 'uri' string in the last entry doesn't include the leading forward slash, but aside from that I'm stumped.

I tested the pattern match using the built-in 'RegEx Test' tool, and if I passed `/subfolder/javascript.js` I get `http://library.provider.com/javascript.js` as expected.

It seems that I am really close to the answer, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following config in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^subfolder/(.*) http://library.provider.com/$1 [NC,P]
```